# timeout when initiating a sshfs connection

Tags: boot, fstab, timeout, sshfs

I have following line in `/etc/fstab`

```
192.168.1.10:/data   /mnt/data  fuse.sshfs  rw,noauto,nosuid,nodev,noexec,_netdev
```

and following line in `/etc/rc.local`:

```
mount /mnt/data
```

During boot process, the share is mounted automatically from a remote server via sshfs.

Sometimes the server is offline and the connection times out indefinitely and my boot process stalls

How can I set a reasonable timeout, so that if server is unreachable, the mount skips after 5 seconds or so ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sshfs allows ssh client options to be used.

You want to use the ssh option `ConnectTimeout=5`.

So in the 4th field of your fstab line, append `,ConnectTimeout=5`.